# bootstrap css file - please explain what does the font code means

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking at the bootstrap at bit more details and came across this

```
font: 0/0 a;
```

What does this code do? 0px size... 0px line height maybe? What is this a? what font family is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0 is a short hand of 0px. 0 is the only one number you can use as short hand.

"font: 0/0 a" means font-size/line-height font name

Answer (score 3):

[Source](http://nicolasgallagher.com/another-css-image-replacement-technique/)

"`font:0/0 a` – a shorthand property that **zeros** out the **font size** and **line-height**. The `a` value acts as a **very short font-family** (an idea taken from the [BEM implementation of this method](https://github.com/bem/bem-bl/blob/c451e7bd44b298d23c7fff9bfafe1f0a514f6aaf/blocks-desktop/b-icon/b-icon.css)).

The CSS validator complains that using 0/0 in the shorthand font property is not valid, but every browser accepts it and this appears to be an error in the validator. Using font:0px/0 a passes validation but it displayed as font:0/0 a in the code that the validator flags as valid."

**Note**: The `font-family: a` present in the shorthand above is an invalid one. It is put there only to make the expression valid.

Comment: Yes I saw that too . However dont understand what the statement means.. Well I understand the concept of zero font size and line height. But what is very short font family? Can you please clarify a bit more.. thanks in advance

Comment: It is only there to complete the expression, otherwise it is invalid. But normally, this font-family is inexistent.